# E4 compat app: "Pre-load" perspective from fragment via e4xmi-defined menu

Tags: user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4, perspective

I develop a Neon-based compatibility mode Eclipse RCP.

In a plugin, I add a new perspective via `fragment.e4xmi` as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<fragment:ModelFragments xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:advanced="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/advanced" xmlns:basic="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/basic" xmlns:fragment="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/fragment" xmi:id="_BxaXACerEeWxCPrV0pAZQQ">
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_j2XU0CE8EeicB9o_IvsRpg" featurename="snippets" parentElementId="org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application">
    <elements xsi:type="advanced:Perspective" xmi:id="_-awZgCE8EeicB9o_IvsRpg" elementId="net.my.editor.ui.perspective.editing" selectedElement="_HyeW0CE9EeicB9o_IvsRpg" label="Editing Perspective">
      <children xsi:type="basic:PartSashContainer" xmi:id="_HyeW0CE9EeicB9o_IvsRpg" elementId="net.my.editor.ui.partsashcontainer.0" selectedElement="_KOMLUCE9EeicB9o_IvsRpg" horizontal="true">
        <children xsi:type="basic:PartStack" xmi:id="_iprjYCH5EeilmepNhpTrFQ" elementId="net.my.editor.ui.partstack.navigation" containerData="20">
          <children xsi:type="advanced:Placeholder" xmi:id="_RcRHECH3EeilmepNhpTrFQ" elementId="net.my.plugin.views.navigation" ref="_F0GUoCH4EeilmepNhpTrFQ" closeable="true"/>
        </children>
        <children xsi:type="basic:PartStack" xmi:id="_KOMLUCE9EeicB9o_IvsRpg" elementId="net.my.editor.ui.partstack.editing" containerData="80" selectedElement="_0KJQ0CH2EeilmepNhpTrFQ">
          <children xsi:type="basic:Part" xmi:id="_0KJQ0CH2EeilmepNhpTrFQ" elementId="net.my.editor.ui.part.splitter" contributionURI="bundleclass://net.my.editor.ui/net.my.editor.ui.parts.SplitterView" label="splitter" iconURI="platform:/plugin/net.my.editor.ui/icons/Sample.png" closeable="true"/>
          <children xsi:type="basic:Part" xmi:id="_LXR6UCE9EeicB9o_IvsRpg" elementId="net.my.editor.ui.parts.MyEditor.static" contributionURI="bundleclass://net.my.editor.ui/net.my.editor.ui.parts.MyEditor" label="Editor" iconURI="platform:/plugin/net.my.editor.ui/icons/Sample.png">
          </children>
        </children>
      </children>
    </elements>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_HSMw4FS4Eeacy4vmBL0tEQ" featurename="sharedElements" parentElementId="IDEWindow">
    <elements xsi:type="basic:Part" xmi:id="_F0GUoCH4EeilmepNhpTrFQ" elementId="net.my.plugin.views.navigation" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView"/>
  </fragments>
</fragment:ModelFragments>
```

The perspective works fine and I can open it from the *Perspective Toolbar*.

I want to provide a menu item in the main menu which opens the perspective programmatically. It is here I'm running into issues.

I've added a menu item, command and handler to programmatically open the perspective. In it, the `EModelService` cannot find the perspective unless it has been opened beforehand.

I.e., `modelService.find(perspectiveId, application)` returns `null`, unless the perspective has been previously opened via the Perspective Toolbar (at which point its icon also appears in the toolbar for itself).

Hence my question: **Is there a way that I can "pre-load" the perspective so that it is available in the model at the time the menu entry is handled, even if the perspective hasn't been opened before?**

Comment: Have you tried `EPartService.switchPerspective`?

Comment: Yes, that gives me `!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-03-07 13:40:23.420
!MESSAGE Perspective with ID ... not found in the current window.`. Wondering whether defining the perspective in `snippets` is perhaps the cause for this, and whether I should attach it someplace else (based on the application window)? Application is `org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application`.

Comment: It is really strange that `EPartService.switchPerspective(String ID)` doesn't work. I encountered the issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to make it work by adding the perspective programmatically to the children of the `PerspectiveStack` parent of the currently active perspective.

Smells of brute force, so I'd still be interested in a better solution!

```java
MPerspective myPerspective = null;
List<MUIElement> snips = application.getSnippets();
for (MUIElement snip : snips) {
    if (snip.getElementId().equals(myPerspectiveId)) {
        if (snip instanceof MPerspective) {
            myPerspective = (MPerspective) snip;
        }
    }
}
if (myPerspective != null) {
    MPerspective activePerspective = modelService.getActivePerspective(window);
    MPerspectiveStack perspectiveStack = (MPerspectiveStack) (MElementContainer<?>) activePerspective
    .getParent();
    perspectiveStack.getChildren().add(myPerspective);
    partService.switchPerspective(myPerspective);
}
```